# How do I get length of the movie using Imdbpy library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, imdb, imdbpy

I know I may be asking pretty silly question. But I haven't found an answer for the question.

How can I get the length of a movie using Imdbpy library?

I do see that there is duration for any movie in imdb.com but I didn't find any key or variable to get the length of the movie using Imdbpy.

I have gone through the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/imdbpy/stable/imdbpy.pdf), but it didn't help out.

I know we can scrape the length of the movie using requests and beautifulsoup libraries. But I was looking for an efficient way to do it using Imdbpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries.

I should be looking for **runtimes** key in movie dictionary. BTW I didn't find this in documentation.